# First person shooter for Ubuntu

Tags: gratis, ubuntu, game

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 Laptop with 8GB RAM and Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 2020M @ 2.40GHz Processor. For this system I am looking for an easy to install first person shooter. It does not have to have the latest graphics, but an easy-to-install game with fullscreen mode, with a fluid gameplay possible.

Must have:

- Easy to install, best with apt-get install
- Fullscreen
- Free
- Easy to install (I cannot emphasize this enough. I do not want to track down hundreds of packages I need to install with configure/make/make install - I guess you know what I mean)

Other info:

- Does not have to be multiplayer

Additional info:

I try to use the Software Center, but in most cases I get the following error message:

> Package dependencies cannot be resolved

Answer (score 2):

Any of the Quake series, Urban Terror or anything else based on the Quake3/io engine, Xonotic.

I'll recommend Xonotic of them all though... http://www.xonotic.org/

If you don't mine playing via web browser and flash plugin (I use chromium+pepperflash-nonfree) http://tankionline.com has a nice tank fighting game that I play a lot

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention that the games must be free (as in freedom), therefore here is the [Steam list of shooters for Linux](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Reviews_DESC&term=shooter&tags=19&os=linux). Beyond that, [Xononic](http://www.xonotic.org/) is arguably the best open-source shooter out there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Sauerbraten](http://sauerbraten.org/), because it has better singleplayer and performs better on an older system. Xonotic is amazing as well, but needs a more powerful PC.

You can install it via `apt-get sauerbraten`